# FBX importer python error

Tags: python, import, .fbx

I'm trying to open an FBX file in Blender 2.9, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? `AssertionError`?

The file opens fine in the web-based [Three.js Editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), so I know the Three.js FBX loader works. It also opens in Windows 3D Viewer, just not in Blender. I've checked my FBX IO add-on, and I have version `4.21.3` installed. Do I need to update my FBX import add-on? If so, where do I download it from? [The docs don't specify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html) which version is the latest.

Comment: Please go for the last error it shows: `assert val>=0 and val < length(enum_items)`, seems like the file contain custom properties but it is not in normal format? Without the file, we cannot go further detection since assertion is made by coder, not program itself.

Comment: @HikariTW Thanks! Do you think that, since `read_custom_properties` is happening inside `blen_read_material` that it's an issue with the material?

Comment: Definitely yes, it seems that the decoder is not able to deal with certain of structure in your materials. As I said, the assertion is 'made' intentionally. Which is, the script is not able to deal with this thing, and there is no work around at the time script is written.